# Abort Capistrano deploy bundler:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano, digital-ocean, ubuntu-16.04

Following this [tutorial](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04) from GoRails I'm getting this error when I try to deploy on Ubuntu 16.04 on Digital Ocean.

`$ cap production deploy --trace`

Trace [Here](http://pastebin.com/iEETPM1q)

```
** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:

 DEBUG [9a2c15d9] Command: [ -d /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734/public/system ]
 DEBUG [9a2c15d9] Finished in 0.181 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [86a233a2] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/shared/public/system /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734/public/system as deployer@138.68.8.2…
 DEBUG [86a233a2] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/shared/public/system /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/…
  INFO [86a233a2] Finished in 0.166 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  DEBUG [07f5e5a2] Running [ -L /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734/public/assets ] as deployer@138.68.8.255
 DEBUG [07f5e5a2] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734/public/assets ]
 DEBUG [07f5e5a2] Finished in 0.166 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [5e61eaf3] Running [ -d /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734/public/assets ] as deployer@138.68.8.255
 DEBUG [5e61eaf3] Command: [ -d /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734/public/assets ]
 DEBUG [5e61eaf3] Finished in 0.168 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [52076052] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/shared/public/assets /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734/public/assets as deployer@138.68.8.2…
 DEBUG [52076052] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/shared/public/assets /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/…
  INFO [52076052] Finished in 0.167 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [2a6bf02b] Running if test ! -d /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734'"…
 DEBUG [2a6bf02b] Command: if test ! -d /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734'…
 DEBUG [2a6bf02b] Finished in 0.164 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [f4b636e3] Running $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet as deployer@138.6…
 DEBUG [f4b636e3] Command: cd /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/releases/20160829222734 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle inst…
 DEBUG [f4b636e3]   bash: line 1:  3509 Killed                  $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/shared/bundle --without development test -…
```

My Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
# If you are using rbenv add these lines:
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1'

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
# require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

I'm stuck, don't know why is aborting cap.

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you are running out of RAM? If there isn't enough memory the kernel will kill the process. Check `/var/log/syslog` for clues, maybe.

Comment: I solve the problem adding `set :bundle_env_variables, { 'NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES' => 1 }` on deploy.rb file, executing a bundle install on my server i found a problem installing Nokogiri, searching on google I found that problem was for the system libraries. thanks for help